# Wordpress, Page Loads Wrong, All Browsers on one specific machine

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, dns

Ok, I'm stumped.

I use Wordpress for my art site, and work on a home built Windows 7 machine. Until the yesterday, I'd had no issues, but suddenly I can't use the media library, UI scripts aren't loading correctly on the admin pages and nothing quite works. The behavior is the same in Firefox, Chrome and IE... but only on my workstation.

On my wife's computer, another windows 7 box that I built and maintain, the dashboard and admin tools work fine. On my ipad and iphone, they are fine. At the web host's end, fine. So it's not a Wordpress issue, it's not a PHP issue. It's something about how my machine is loading the page.

Things I've tried:

Uninstall AV and Firewall, to get them out of the way. No effect.
Dumping Cache, all browswers. No effect.
Flushed DNS. No effect.
Reset Winsock. No effect.
Created new user, fresh profile. No effect.

Any ideas? What could break a single specific page in all browsers on a Windows 7 box?

Comment: Can you confirm that you haven't disabled JavaScript? Are there any errors in the developer console? Have you got any adblocking software running?

Comment: I can confirm that JavaScript was enabled and that there were errors in the consoles of all three browsers, the same errors. However, I made an error in my original submission, and that error was the cause of the problem. I had been using Bitdefender Free as my AV. I closed it out, but had not removed it. Apparently however, it has a service of some sort that runs in the background. I noticed late that night (early the next morning) that it had updated itself that morning. I uninstalled it completely, and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Good to hear! Can you post what you did to resolve it and the background processes that were blocking the JS as an answer to help others?

Answer (score 1):

Problem turned out to be my failure to uninstall the AV (Bitdefender Free) properly. It had updated on the day in question and was false positive blocking Wordpress's loads of Jquery and other scripts. A complete uninstall remedied the problem.